# Some result about hyperbolic link complements and (ideal) polyhedral decompositions

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, knot-theory

The complement of the Borromean rings in $S^3$ can be obtained by gluing together two (regular) ideal hyperbolic octahedra. I seem to recall a result (possibly bearing Epstein's name?) about other hyperbolic link complements also having this sort of ideal octahedral decomposition but I'm unable to find such a result when Googling about.

Does anyone have any ideas what result I may be thinking of and where to find it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, MathOverflow is a good place to try, several people over there know the literature really well.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I thought this question may have been a bit too soft of MathOverflow, but I'll definitely move it over there if I don't have a response here by the end of the week.